# Difference between req.param = function(){} and req.param = function param() {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, pure-js

I was looking into express.js repository and noticed that, for example, authors created req object and his methods by using this code:

```
req.param = function param(name, defaultValue) {}...
```

but in some others methods they have this code:

```
req.accepts = function(){}...
```

So, what's the difference between those two approaches ?
Couldn't they write just:

```
req.param = function(name, defaultValue){}...
```

Is there a difference in functionality between those two approaches ?